# How to Factorize 170 digits long BigInteger

Tags: java, factorization

I need to factorize 170 digits long integer, I know that this number have 2 factors. I have tried Pollard Rho algorithm but unfortunately this is not big enough hammer to crush it. The algorithm does not end. Did I make any mistake?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class PollardRho {
    private final static BigInteger ZERO = new BigInteger("0");
    private final static BigInteger ONE = new BigInteger("1");
    private final static BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
    private final static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static BigInteger rho(BigInteger N) {
        BigInteger divisor;
        BigInteger c = new BigInteger(N.bitLength(), random);
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger(N.bitLength(), random);
        BigInteger xx = x;

        // check divisibility by 2
        if (N.mod(TWO).compareTo(ZERO) == 0)
            return TWO;

        do {
            x = x.multiply(x).mod(N).add(c).mod(N);
            xx = xx.multiply(xx).mod(N).add(c).mod(N);
            xx = xx.multiply(xx).mod(N).add(c).mod(N);
            divisor = x.subtract(xx).gcd(N);
        } while ((divisor.compareTo(ONE)) == 0);

        return divisor;
    }

    public static void factor(BigInteger N) {
        if (N.compareTo(ONE) == 0)
            return;
        if (N.isProbablePrime(20)) {
            System.out.println(N);
            return;
        }
        BigInteger divisor = rho(N);
        factor(divisor);
        factor(N.divide(divisor));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger N = new BigInteger(
                "46862651776313668832684618638310007043245135907468247470585960688008180534742005269578548831878148535158738789789506710579367525183636389872513135592162572724499935530721");
        factor(N);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is this code not working? (If so, please describe what you expect and what is actually does, in detail) Or are you asking for a code review? (In that case, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the place to be, not stackoverflow.com)

Comment: What are you trying to do, break an RSA private key?

Comment: "The algorithm does not end." How many hours/days/months/years have you wait before saying this? If fctorizing 170 digits long integers was easy we'd be in big trouble.

Comment: @StephaneM I waited few minutes.

Comment: Test your code on a smaller number.  Generate two 10 digit primes and multiply them.  Does your code factorise the product correctly?  How long does it take?  Do the same for two 20 digit primes.  Time it again.  That will let you estimate how long to wait for an answer for your current problem.

Comment: "Few minutes!?" Pollard Rho will take many centuries to split a 170-digit semi-prime. If you really need an answer, find an implementation of the number field sieve, set it spinning on several thousand computers, and come back for the output in a year. But I can tell you that your Pollard Rho implementation looks basically correct, though I didn't run it to be sure.